# Simple example of idempotent but not commutative nor associative binary operator?

Tags: binary-operations

Is there a simple example of a binary operation that is idempotent, but not commutative nor associative?

Comment: The term idempotent refers to objects where we can perform a binary operation, not to the operation itself.

Comment: An idempotent element $a$ is one such that $a\cdot a=a$. Do you want $a\cdot a=a$ for all elements in the set?

Comment: yes, I want a*a=a for all a in the set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about $a\oplus b=pa+(1-p)b$ for $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $\{0,\frac12,1\}\not\ni p\in\mathbb R$?